# when i try "make", i get error: identifier “nullptr” is undefined

Tags: c++, cmake

When I try OpenPose Building, I get error: identifier “nullptr” is undefined.

I follow the instructions on the site to install OpenPose　and I have error in "OpenPose Building".
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md#clone-openpose

```
my@PC:~/openpose/build$ make -j`nproc`

Scanning dependencies of target openpose_caffe
[ 12%] Creating directories for 'openpose_caffe'
[ 25%] No download step for 'openpose_caffe'
[ 37%] [ 50%] No patch step for 'openpose_caffe'
No update step for 'openpose_caffe'
[ 62%] Performing configure step for 'openpose_caffe'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found GFlags: /usr/include  
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so)
-- Found Glog: /usr/include  
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so)
-- Found PROTOBUF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so  
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/bin/protoc
-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so  
-- CUDA detected: 8.0
-- Found cuDNN: ver. 5.1.10 found (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so)
-- Automatic GPU detection failed. Building for all known architectures.
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: sm_30 sm_35 sm_50 sm_52 sm_60 sm_61
-- Found Atlas: /usr/include  
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include library: /usr/lib/libatlas.so lapack: /usr/lib/liblapack.so
-- Python interface is disabled or not all required dependencies found. Building without it...
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "1.9.1") 
-- 
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   1.0.0
--   Git               :   1.0-141-g974172c
--   System            :   Linux
--   C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/c++
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   OFF
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   OFF
--   CPU_ONLY          :   OFF
--   USE_OPENCV        :   OFF
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   OFF
--   USE_LMDB          :   OFF
--   USE_NCCL          :   OFF
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
--   USE_HDF5          :   ON
-- 
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.54)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 2.5.0)
--   CUDA              :   Yes (ver. 8.0)
-- 
-- NVIDIA CUDA:
--   Target GPU(s)     :   Auto
--   GPU arch(s)       :   sm_30 sm_35 sm_50 sm_52 sm_60 sm_61
--   cuDNN             :   Yes (ver. 5.1.10)
-- 
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /home/miyo/openpose/build/caffe
-- 
CMake Warning (dev) in src/caffe/CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0022 is not set: INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link
  interface.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "caffe" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property which differs from
  its LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties.

  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:

    caffeproto;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so;$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so>;$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so>;-lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcurand.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcublas.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so;/usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libcblas.so;/usr/lib/libatlas.so

  LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES:

    caffeproto;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcurand.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcublas.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so;/usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libcblas.so;/usr/lib/libatlas.so

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/miyo/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_caffe-build
[ 75%] Performing build step for 'openpose_caffe'
[  1%] Running C++/Python protocol buffer compiler on /home/miyo/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
Scanning dependencies of target caffeproto
[  1%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffeproto.dir/__/__/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libcaffeproto.a
[  1%] Built target caffeproto
[  1%] [  1%] [  2%] [  2%] [  4%] [  5%] [  6%] [  6%] [  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_sgd_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o
[  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_adam_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_deconv_layer.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_adagrad_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_rmsprop_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_nesterov_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_adadelta_solver.cu.o
[  8%] [  8%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_lrn_layer.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_hdf5_data_layer.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cu.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h(432): error: expected a ";"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h(432): error: expected a ";"


...


/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(202): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(202): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(221): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(221): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(221): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(240): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(240): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(240): error: expected a ";"

Error limit reached.
100 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001d71_00000000-17_math_functions.compute_61.cpp1.ii".
Compilation terminated.
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o.cmake:264 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/miyo/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_caffe-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [caffe/src/openpose_caffe-stamp/openpose_caffe-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Ubuntu 14.04,
Cuda 8.0,
cudnn 5.1,
gcc 4.9,
g++ 4.9

- Additional notes -

I am multiposting here.
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/981
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51408/openpose%e3%81%ae%e3%83%93%e3%83%ab%e3%83%89%e6%99%82%e3%81%aberror-identifier-nullptr-is-undefined%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b

I ran the following code but I could not improve this problem.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

- Additional notes２ -

  my@PC:~$ cc --version
  cc (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.9.4
  Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

  my@PC:~$ c++ --version
  c++ (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.9.4
  Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Considering you have tagged your question for only the C programming language, there is no `nullptr` keyword or identifier in C. ***But*** since it seems you're building a C++ project (and therefore miss-tagged your question) the old compiler you have use an old version of the C++ standard by default, an old version which didn't specify the `nullptr` identifier. Either update your compiler, or submit a bug report to the project telling them to add a check for C++ standard flags.

Comment: You should upgrade your distribution. Ubuntu 14 is ancient. And GCC 4.9 is obsolete. Current GCC is GCC8

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, the label "C" is an input mistake. Thank you for your comment.
I use version 4.9 for both gcc and g ++.
I think that nullptr can be used if version is 4.6 or higher. Please let me know if there is any mistake in my understanding.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch For similar problems dealt with in the following sites, respondents recommend using GCC 4.6 or 4.9.
Is this also a problem with GCC 8? https://github.com/torch/torch7/issues/682

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I wouldn't say that gcc 4.9 is obsolete as current RedHat comes with 4.8.5 and there is no update in official repositories. So I'm pretty sure 4.8.5 is widely used on commercial servers and enterprise linux. In 4.8.5 you can use nullptr.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: On the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) official website, **[GCC 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/) is *explicitly* no longer maintained**. The fact that some distributions are still using it don't matter.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch RedHat runs on 65%-80% of (linux) enterprise servers. 4.8.5 may be no longer maintained but it is widely used.

Comment: But OP is not using RedHat. And the current [Ubuntu desktop distro](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) is 18.04.1

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But an upgrade won't fix the problem as 4.8.5 supports nullptr

Comment: Newer GCC are much more C++11 compliant than older ones. And the latest C++ standard is C++17 (which GCC 4.8 don't support)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch GCC 4.8.1 is fully C++11 compliant

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ubuntu 18 is not in the list of supported OS. The latest supported Ubuntu is Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.1 is marked LTS and is generally (and notably for software builds) upward compatible with previous ones

Answer (score 3):

I believe that GCC 4.9 should be sufficient. The caveat is that it does not use C++11 *by default*, so you have to add `--std=c++11` somewhere in the `Makefile` where the `CXXFLAGS` are defined. The developers of the software package might use a newer version of GCC which uses C++14 by default, like GCC 8.2.

As this is a CMake project, you can either add

```
add_definitions('--std=c++11')
```

to the `CMakeLists.txt` or add

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

if your version of CMake supports it.